# php wp_query to get one value from multiple values in variable - the values separated by a comma

Tags: php, wordpress

This might seem a little odd as a method.

I have posts on my wordpress website, which has a custom field called '`login_email`'

In my theme files, I have this query...

```
$press = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'download',
    'post_status'   => 'private',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'login_email',
            'value' => $current_user->user_login,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )      
));
```

This simply retrieves private posts which has the `login_email` custom field value which that matches `$current_user->user_login`

Currently in my `login_email` custom field i have this value...

```
josh@samplemail.uk.com
```

No what I would like to be able to do is add more emails to this custom field seperate by a comma like this...

```
josh@samplemail.uk.com, colin@samplemail.uk.com, jimbo@samplemail.uk.com
```

...and for my query above to be able to recognise one email out of this list.

For example if the user `colin@samplemail.uk.com` is logged in, then because colins email exists in this custom field (along with josh & jimbo's email) then the post will be returned in the query.

I hope this makes some kind of sense. Let me know if I need to elaborate more.

It's like I need to modify the compare in the query - but these are the only options I can find...

**compare (string) - Operator to test. Possible values are '=', '!=', '>', '>=', '<', '<=', 'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE', 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', 'NOT BETWEEN', 'EXISTS' (only in WP >= 3.5), and 'NOT EXISTS' (also only in WP >= 3.5). Default value is '='.** [Source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

...I've tested EXISTS but does not return any posts.

Has any one got a clever fix or idea?

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 0):

Please try the operator `IN`. This will allow you to search in multiple emails.

Follow the `IN` clause written here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14997

Comment: I tried this but no post are returned. And the current username is in the `login_email` string.

Comment: What is a clause? Do I need to install a function or is the operator IN meant to work?

Comment: Thats odd, IN doesnt seem to find the emails in the custom field. Hmm I wonder why that could be